# Are Google App Engine Java endpoints suitable for storing large datasets?

Tags: java, sql, performance, google-app-engine, endpoint

The Google App Engine (GAE) provides developers with a platform which can be used for serving data to numerous users. Developers can program these endpoints in [Python, Go, PHP and Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs).

I wish to create an extensive database of users in the GAE, accessible via a REST interface to a persistent Java application. I know that there is [support for SQL databases](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) by the platform, which is a conventional solution, but I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same in Java and take advantage of the functionality the language has to offer through JDO/JPA, whilst still providing the performance and efficiency of standard SQL.

Specifically, what I'm asking for is whether a `TABLE` in MySQL could be implemented just as efficiently as a `@PersistenceCapable` `List<UserData>` in Java, that resides at one of these GAE endpoints.

For example, this would result in a tradeoff between a `"SELECT * WHERE _Name EQUALS 'bill'"`and

```
final List<User> lMatchingUsers = new List<User>();
for(int i = 0; i < this.getUserList().size(); i++) {
  if(this.getUserList().get(i).getName().equals("bill")) {
     lMatchingUsers.add(this.getUserList().get(i));
  }
}
return lMatchingUsers;
```

I have a hard time believing the latter is going to be as effective!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/), it's simply a service to provide a REST API to your application — they do not provide storage.

In the case of Java, you would write your business logic as normal, then annotate your classes to expose them in your REST API.  Cloud Endpoints will generate your client libraries (Android, iOS, Javascript) for you to call your API methods remotely.

How you store your data is up to your application - i.e. what you implement in Java.  That could be Cloud SQL, Datastore, or something else running on a Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try to clear up the question some more. What I am asking is whether the persistence methods such as JDO/JPA would be suitable for the proposed application?

Comment: If they're suitable for an App Engine application, they're suitable for Cloud Endpoints.  Personally I don't use JDO/JPA as they don't (for me) map well to Datastore (we don't use SQL). All Cloud Endpoints is really doing is serializing/deserializing your Java object to client-size equivalents.

Comment: Okay, well I'm wondering about whether I'd suffer from a serious loss of performance when using JDO/JPA when compared to an SQL equivalent. What do you mean when you say if they're suitable for an App Engine application? As an example, do you think the GAE could support data storage and performance on the scale of a social network?

Comment: _"As an example, do you think the GAE could support data storage and performance on the scale of a social network"_ — Snapchat runs on App Engine.

Comment: That's certainly encouraging! Do you have any idea whether this implementation uses Java persistence?